# Got stuck while uploading ipa file to app store connect

Tags: ios, xcode9, application-loader

I was successfully uploading .ipa file to App Store Connect after archiving my swift project until yesterday, but after doing some minor changes i wanted to upload again and it always gets stuck at this point and it does not progress for hours.

[image: stuck at uploading]

I know my upload speed is slow, the thing is why suddenly it stops at this point and does not progress? I did upload 4 times before this happened and there was no problem.

Comment: what is your internet speed?

Comment: check firewall may be block itunes

Comment: if you have slow internet then you can export and upload using application loader so in application loader you can see how many size of your ipa and also display how many size of file is upload.

Comment: I think it's related to a problem with the Internet Service Provider in my local area. There was no problem with the firewall, i also tried exporting ipa but it was slow again. It took a very long time uploading through archieve but now it's done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is solved now, it was related to a problem with my ISP. Because network was so slow, sometimes connection was restarting and it got stuck.

Comment: So, how to solve this issue, if some other developer will face the same issue?

Comment: @MandeepSingh Most probably problem occurs due to connection issues, can try connecting via vpn or without vpn. Also can try exporting .ipa file locally, for more details, have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/58028679/4629420

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was either the double NAT (two routers), or the fact that the second one is doing load-balancing between a LTE connection and the DSL connection from the first router.

When I switched to using my phone as a hotspot instead, the upload worked flawlessly.