# How to upload IPA file to App Store from Mac OS X Catalina

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, phonegap, ipa

I just created an app in Apple Developer portal and now I want to upload an IPA file created from Phonegap to App Store. How can I do it? In Mac OS X Catalina there is no iTunes app and I don't find in XCode > Open Developer Tool > Application loader.

UPDATE: I can open Archives window in XCode but my app does not appear in the list.

Comment: can youopen the project that phonegap create on xcode and archive on xcode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload IPA now that Application Loader is no longer included in Xcode 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976017/how-to-upload-ipa-now-that-application-loader-is-no-longer-included-in-xcode-11)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `xcrun altool` command line:

```
xcrun altool --upload-app --type ios --file <Path-to-ipa> --username <Username> --password <One-time-pass>
```

Remember to use the one time pass from https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage .

No double quote for the content, just replace the < Path-to-ipa >,< Username > and < One-time-pass >!

I'm using Xcode11.1.

Click [here to the source answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58074917/9060881)!

Comment: for me its only working with double qoutes in Xcode 11.3.1...

Answer (score 9):

And if you don't want to used cli you can use Transporter

This app allows developers to easily upload files to App Store Connect and more.

Available in the Mac AppStore. (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12)

Comment: is it slow? my connection is good, but after 75% it's returned to 0 :\

Comment: Best! This should be the accepted answer - no app-specific-passwords needed and you have nice UI with error messages and status.