# How can i solve this problem with iOS game upload?

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, app-store-connect

I´m getting an error all the time when uploading an update for my latest iOS game, yesterday I uploaded the 1st version and everything went good, but today I´m trying to update it and I´m getting all the time this:

ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app contains one or more corrupted binaries. Rebuild the app and resubmit.. If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app. If so, they must be removed. For further information, visit the Technical Support Information at http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

I tried multiple things and nothing worked... I saw lots of blogs and videos and nothing... Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue since yesterday. Seems to be a problem on Apple's side, hopefully they will fix it soon. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/127678

Comment: Same issue here. What's the best and fastest way of bringing this to Apple's attention?

Comment: @almas I hope so...

Comment: I did send a report to Apple. Hopefully we will be back on track soon enough!

Answer (score 0):

facing very similar issue. Apple email is not specific but the same vague statement like above. our app uses unity3d as well.

Comment: It is a problem with App store connect, they are already working to fix it.
https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. It doesn’t provide any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It's working again!

I uploaded an update for review through the Transporter app. More info here: [How to upload IPA now that Application Loader is no longer included in Xcode 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976017/how-to-upload-ipa-now-that-application-loader-is-no-longer-included-in-xcode-11)

Good luck =)